# How to find $a+b$?

Tags: calculus

If 
$$
f(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
e^{ax} +3,& x<0\\
 ax^2-3x+b & x≥0
\end{array}\right.
$$
is differentiable at $x=0$, then $a+b$ is

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: What have you tried? Recall that $f$ is differentiable if the limit of the difference quotient from the left is equal to that from the right.

Comment: I tried differntiating both sides and setting them equal to each other, then plugged 0 in for x, but it didn't work out

Answer (score 5):

You need the function to be continuous, so the limits from each side must be equal. That gives you one equation. The derivatives must also agree, so differentiate the formulas on each side and set them equal at $0$. That is a second equation.

Answer (score 2):

For a function to be differentiable at a certain point, the function and the derivative must both be continuous at that point.

$$
f(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
e^{ax} +3,& x<0\\
 ax^2-3x+b & x\ge0
\end{array}\right.
$$
means that
$$
f'(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
ae^{ax},& x<0\\
2ax-3 & x>0
\end{array}\right.
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ultra pedantic remark: the differentiation is not necessarily correct at $x=0$.

Comment: Better now, @JpMcCarthy?

Comment: I set the derivatives equal and got a=3... but how do I find b?

Comment: Plug $x = 0$ to $f(x)$ and set $b$ so that it's continuous.

Comment: Yes +1 for you.

Comment: You actually need to do the continuity BEFORE the differentiability. Consider the Heaviside function...the derivatives match up but it is not differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

You use the fact that a function $f$ is differentiable at $0$ exactly when
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}
$$
exists. That is when the right hand limit is equal to the left hand limit. All you have to do is to compute
$$
\lim_{h\to 0^{-}} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} \quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}
$$
That is
$$
\lim_{h\to 0^{-}} \frac{e^{ah} - 4}{h} \quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{ah^2 - 3h + b - b}{h}
$$
have to equal. This will give you the equation(s) that you need.

EDIT: After reading Ross'answer, I realize that you should also consider
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x).
$$
We need this to make $f$ continuous at $0$.